# Using animated graph with Tkinter GUI python

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib, tkinter, arduino

I am developing a python code where my computer reads data being transmitted using serial communication and my program presents this data in graphical format. New data is received every 0.1 seconds after which the graph is updated.

The code is:

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use("TkAgg")
from matplotlib import *
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg, NavigationToolbar2TkAgg
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
import matplotlib.animation as animation
from random import *
from Serial import *
import Tkinter as tk
import ttk
import xlwt
import serial

COMPORT = "COM7"
BUAD = 115200

def init():
    connected = False
    global ser
    global COMPORT, BUAD
    ser = serial.Serial(COMPORT, BUAD)
    while not connected:
        serin = ser.read()
        connected = True

def TransmitCommand(Command):
    SCommand = Command + 'y'
    ser.write(SCommand)

def TransmitData(Data):
    SData = str(Data) + 'y'
    ser.write(SData)

def ClosePort():
    ser.close()

def RecieveData():
    return ser.readline()


################################################################################
############################    Graph1   #######################################
################################################################################
F1 = Figure(figsize=(15,8), dpi=80)
rc("font", size = 10)
Figure
a1 = F1.add_subplot(111)
tList = []
xList = []
yList = []
zList = []
fList = []
xfList = []
yfList = []
zfList = []
fxList = []
fyList = []
fzList = []
t = 0.00
t1 = 0
x = 0
y = 0
z = 0
ex = 0
ey = 0
ez = 0
r1 = 0
r2 = 0
r3 = 0
l = 0
txp = 0
typ = 0
tzp = 0
global fx1, fy1, fz1
fx1 = 0.00000
fy1 = 0.00000
fz1 = 0.00000

PPS1 = 1

def Play1():
    global PPS1
    TransmitCommand('SendData')
    #print 'Done'
    PPS1 = 0
def Pause1():
    global PPS1
    TransmitCommand('StopData')
    PPS1 = 1
def Stop1():
    global PPS1
    TransmitCommand('StopData')
    PPS1 = 2
def Extract1():
    pass
def Save1():
    pass


def SaveGraph1():
    pass

def animate1(i):
    global l, ex, ey, ez, t, x, y, z, tList, xList, yList, zList, r1, r2, r3
    global fx1, fy1, fz1, txp, typ, tzp, xt, yt, zt

    if(PPS1 == 0):
        tList.append(t)
        xList.append(x)
        yList.append(y)
        zList.append(z)

        t = int(RecieveData())
        x = int(RecieveData())
        if(l == 0):
            x = (x*0.707)/300
        else:
            x = ex - (x*0.707)/300
        if(x > 0):
            if(xList[l-1] == 0)|(xList[l-1] < 0):
                fx1 = (1.0/(t - txp))*1000
                txp = t
                r1 = 1
        y = int(RecieveData())
        if(l == 0):
            y = (y*0.707)/300
        else:
            y = ey - (y*0.707)/300
        if(y > 0):
            if(yList[l-1] == 0)|(yList[l-1] < 0):
                fy1 = (1.0/(t - typ))*1000
                typ = t
                r2 = 1
        z = int(RecieveData())
        if(l == 0):
            z = (z*0.707)/300
        else:
            z = ez - (z*0.707)/300
        if(z > 0):
           if(zList[l-1] == 0)|(zList[l-1] < 0):
                fz1 = (1.0/(t - tzp))*1000
                tzp = t
                r3 = 1

        if(l == 0):
            ex = x
            ey = y
            ez = z

        l = l+1

    if(PPS1 == 2):    
        tList = []
        xList = []
        yList = []
        zList = []
        t = 0
        x = 0
        y = 0
        z = 0    

    a1.clear()
    a1.plot(tList, xList, label = "ax")
    a1.plot(tList, yList, 'r', label = "ay")
    a1.plot(tList, zList, 'g', label = "az")
    a1.set_ylim(-1,1)
    a1.set_xlabel("Time (ms)")
    a1.set_ylabel("Acceleration (g)")
    a1.legend()   

def GenerateGraph1(Master):
    dataPlot = FigureCanvasTkAgg(F1, master=Master)
    dataPlot.show()
    dataPlot.get_tk_widget()

    display1 = tk.Canvas(Master, width=100, height=400, bg ="white")
    display1.pack(side = 'right')
    button1 = tk.Button(display1, text='Play', command=Play1, font='Times 12', bd=5,
                                height = 2, width = 10, anchor = 'w').grid(row = 0, column = 0)
    button2 = tk.Button(display1, text='Pause', command=Pause1, font='Times 12', bd=5,
                                height = 2, width = 10, anchor = 'w').grid(row = 1, column = 0)
    button3 = tk.Button(display1, text='Stop', command=Stop1, font='Times 12', bd=5,
                                height = 2, width = 10, anchor = 'w').grid(row = 2, column = 0)
    button4 = tk.Button(display1, text='Extract Data', command=Extract1, font='Times 12', bd=5,
                                height = 2, width = 10, anchor = 'w').grid(row = 3, column = 0)
    button5 = tk.Button(display1, text='Save Data', command=Save1, font='Times 12', bd=5,
                                height = 2, width = 10, anchor = 'w').grid(row = 4, column = 0)
    button5 = tk.Button(display1, text='Save Graph', command=SaveGraph1, font='Times 12', bd=5,
                                height = 2, width = 10, anchor = 'w').grid(row = 5, column = 0)
    button5 = tk.Button(display1, text='Send Mail', command=Save1, font='Times 12', bd=5,
                                height = 2, width = 10, anchor = 'w').grid(row = 6, column = 0)
    toolbar = NavigationToolbar2TkAgg(dataPlot, Master)
    toolbar.update()
    dataPlot._tkcanvas.pack()

def show_frame():
    frame = GenerateGraph(Graph)
    frame.tkraise()

Main = tk.Tk()
init()
n = ttk.Notebook(Main, width= 800, height = 400)
n.grid(row=6,column=0, columnspan=9)
n.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
n.rowconfigure(6, weight=1)    

f1 = ttk.Frame(n);
n.add(f1, text='Acceleration vs Time')
GenerateGraph1(f1)
ani1 = animation.FuncAnimation(F1, animate1, interval=100)
mainloop()
```

Arduino code is:

```
int toggle1 = 0;
boolean Graph = 0;
int x = 0;
int y = 0;
int z = 0;
int i = 0;

const int groundpin = 18;             // analog input pin 4 -- ground
const int powerpin = 19;              // analog input pin 5 -- voltage
const int xpin = A3;                  // x-axis of the accelerometer
const int ypin = A2;                  // y-axis
const int zpin = A1;                  // z-axis (only on 3-axis models)

#include <elapsedMillis.h>
elapsedMillis timeElapsed;

void Acceleration(){
  Serial.print(timeElapsed);
  Serial.print("\n");
  Serial.print(analogRead(xpin));
  Serial.print("\n");
  Serial.print(analogRead(ypin));
  Serial.print("\n");
  Serial.print(analogRead(zpin));
  Serial.print("\n");
  }

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(115200);
  pinMode(8, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(9, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(xpin, INPUT);
  pinMode(ypin, INPUT);
  pinMode(zpin, INPUT);
  Serial.write('1'); 

  noInterrupts();           // disable all interrupts
  TCCR1A = 0;
  TCCR1B = 0;
  TCNT1  = 0;

  OCR1A = 25000;            // compare match register 16MHz/64/10Hz
  TCCR1B |= (1 << WGM12);   // CTC mode
  TIMSK1 |= (1 << OCIE1A);  // enable timer compare interrupt
  interrupts();             // enable all interrupts
  TCCR1B |= (1 << CS10);
  TCCR1B |= (1 << CS11);

  pinMode(groundpin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(powerpin, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(groundpin, LOW);
  digitalWrite(powerpin, HIGH);
}

ISR(TIMER1_COMPA_vect){
  if(Graph == 1){
    Acceleration();
}}

void loop() {
  String brightness, recieve, r1;
  int b1, b2, ledPin;

  while(Serial.available() == 0) {}
  recieve = Serial.readStringUntil('y');
  r1 = recieve + "t";
  if(recieve == "SendData"){Graph = 1;}
  if(recieve == "StopData"){Graph = 0;timeElapsed = 0;}
  if(recieve == "motor1"){
    ledPin = 8;
    while(Serial.available() == 0){}
    brightness = Serial.readStringUntil('y');
    b1 = brightness.toInt();
    analogWrite(ledPin, b1);}
  if(recieve == "motor2"){
    ledPin = 9;
    while(Serial.available() == 0){}
    brightness = Serial.readStringUntil('y');
    b1 = brightness.toInt();
    analogWrite(ledPin, b1);}
  }
  }
```

I am taking data from a vibration sensor. I used stopwatch to time the difference between the time that the vibrations actually started and the time at which the graph began to show the change in data. For the first data set the time difference was 5 seconds, for data set 2 the difference was 1 minute 10 seconds and for the third set it was 2 minutes. The effect became more pronounced as I added a second graph and the rest of my GUI. I need this software to be able to run for hours which means at one point my GUI might become unresponsive and I also need the data to be real-time. What could be the problem causing this and how do I solve it. There may be a better way to show real-time data in GUI as a graph but since I am new to python I dont know.

Comment: There is _way_ too much code here.  In general for animation you should update existing artists rather than creating new ones every time.  You might want to use capped deques instead of lists.

Answer (score 0):

this simple animation example will plot a new red dot every second, the method should be more stable than what you're doing; I've had an app running over 4 months that plots once a minute like this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import random
import time
plt.ion()

x = 0
while x<100:
    y = random.random()
    plt.plot(x,y,marker='.',c='red')
    x+=1
    time.sleep(1)
    plt.tight_layout()
    plt.show()
    plt.pause(0.1)
```

You said you need it to be "real time", but it may be that the execution time of your code is taking longer than the 0.1 seconds that you get new data.   It might be best to update the graph every 10 data points; or as I'm doing... once a minute.